# Angular 4 - What is the best way to handle the nested Subscriptions in Iterations

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs

I am trying to handle a situation where the subscriptions of http calls are nested in iterations.

1) In first returned observable I will get an object of URLS

2) I need to iterate through these URLS and make http calls on these URls

3) The same case in third step, I will get the urls and do the same as in second

4) finally the data which I get from third step I need to push to final object.

```
let finaldata = [];
this.service1.getstep1Data().subscribe((data1) => {
  // data1 = { name : 'abc', urls : ['http://url1.com','http://url2.com',........,'http://urlz.com']};
  data1.urls.foreach((url) => {
    this.service2.getstep2Data(url).subscribe((data2) => {
      // data2 = { name : 'abc', urls : ['http://url1.com','http://url2.com',........,'http://urlz.com']};
      data2.urls.foreach((url) => {
        this.service3.getfinalData(url).subscribe((data) => {
          // data = ["one","two"...."xyz"]
          finaldata.push(data[0]);
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Now the problem is handling the async calls in Iterations which will not wait for each other.

I want to wait for all Async calls to complete in step two and then execute step three else we don't have URLS for the third step to make rest calls

I know iterating the async calls is not a good practice.

Can some one help me with the best practice for this.

************ Thanks in Advance *************

Comment: You're not using the `url`s returned by the requests to make your second and third http requests, in the code you posted. I guess you want to do something like `this.service2.getstep2Data(url)` instead of `this.service2.getstep2Data()` (same for `service3.getfinalData()`). Am I right? Please update the code in your question accordingly.

Comment: I am using them, If you see the second request - in foreach loop of the urls which I got from the data1 ===> data1.urls.foreach((url) => {})

Comment: You're looping through the array of urls, yes. But what are you actually doing with each url in the array? I believe that you're doing something with them in your real code (like sending a http request to each url), but you're certainly not using a `url` in the code you posted here! To use a `url` your code would have to be something like `data1.urls.foreach((url) => { useTheUrl(url) })`

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding url to the service calls, Now I edited it, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forkJoin` to execute multiple http request and wait for all to complete. It then comes down to mapping to the joined results in the right way and then extracting the data you want.

```ts
import { of, Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, concatMap, map, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.service1.getStep1Data()
  .pipe(
    // we execute multiple getSet2Data requests for each data1 and wait for each to complete
    switchMap(data1 => forkJoin(data1.urls.map(url => this.service2.getStep2Data(url)))),
    // we spread the data2 responses
    switchMap(data2s => of(...data2s)),
    // we execute multiple getfinalData requests for each data2 and emit the results in the
    // order of the data2 results
    concatMap(data2 => forkJoin(data2.urls.map(url => this.service3.getfinalData(url)))),
    // we map to the data we want from the finalData result
    map(data3perData2 => data3perData2.map(data3 => data3[0])),
    // we concatenate the results so that only one array gets emmited
    reduce((acc, data) => acc.concat(data))
  )
  .subscribe(finalData => this.doMyThing(finalData));
```

Alternatively instead of spreading the data2 responses first and reducing the Observable later you could wrap multiple `forkJoin` result with another `forkJoin`.

```ts
this.service1.getStep1Data()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(data1 => forkJoin(data1.urls.map(url => this.service2.getStep2Data(url)))),
    // execute getfinalData for every url from data2 and wait for all results
    // do this for every data2 object 
    switchMap(data2s => forkJoin(data2s.map(data2 => forkJoin(data2.urls.map(url => this.service3.getfinalData(url)))))),
    // fullData will be string[][][], so we flatten that to string[] with the first elements
    // from data3
    map(fullData => [].concat(...fullData).map(data3 => data3[0]))
  )
  .subscribe(finalData => this.doMyThing(finalData));
```

The mapping and reducing at the end depends on how you want your final output to look like.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ze4w4

Comment: HI Fridoo, Many thanks for your detailed stackblitz, I am now able to remove iterations fro my code.......:) ###  Trying to understand these Rxjs Operators in detail but still a confusion on these , it would be really great if you can share me a source where I can get detailed explanation of these operators with examples. Thanks

Comment: @ShivaNayakDharavath I often use https://www.learnrxjs.io, http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html, https://rxmarbles.com . You can also find blog posts to various topics on https://medium.com just search for what you're interested in e.g. https://medium.com/search?q=rxjs%20forkjoin

Answer (score 0):

To make multiple HTTP calls to the server RxJs operator like mergeMap, forkJoin will best way handle this situation.

Following sample example will help in your case.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let character = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1');
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our character
      // results[1] is our character homeworld
      results[0].homeworld = results[1];
      this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but In my case It's not about making multiple HTTP calls, it's about subscribing to calls which are nested and also has Iterations

Answer (score 0):

You can use RXJS forkjoin to achieve the solution.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private appservice: AppService){
    this.appservice.getService1().subscribe(urls=>{
      this.appservice.getService2(urls).subscribe(finalArrayList=>{
        this.appservice.getService3(finalArrayList).subscribe();
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }
}
```

Created Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkh7xr

Comment: You mention `forkJoin` in your text but don't use it in the code of your answer (only in the stackblitz). Please add the full code that is supposed to solve the OPs problem to your answer and not only to your stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Subject](https://blog.cloudboost.io/build-simple-shopping-cart-with-angular-4-observables-subject-subscription-part-2-2d3735cde5f) instead of simple observer. Subject will provide interval updates so will be helpful for synchronized use of  api data.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-subjectdemo)

```
this.api.subjectCreateUser1.subscribe((data1) => {
  if (data1) {
      this.api.subjectCreateUser2.subscribe((data2) => {
          if(data2) {
              this.api.subjectCreateUser3.subscribe((data3) => {
                   if (data3) {
                       console.log(data3);
                   }
              });
          }
      });
  }
});
```

And api calls like below....

```
return this.newHttp.post(this._baseApiUrl, this.data1)
 .subscribe(success => {
   console.log(success);
   this.subjectCreateUser1.next(success);
 }, error => {
   this.subjectCreateUser1.next(error);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have any chance to edit the API calls as it is the existing project where these are used by the team and also If you see my question my subscriptions are iterated in foreach loop and each nested subscription is dependent on its parent response data

Comment: Yes I got that...I didn't add code for Iteration but I made it nested. Trying to convey that 2nd API call will occur only after 1st data will be available. Please check my updated answer.